# Flutter convert String to Json with doubles quotes

Tags: json, flutter

In a project I get a String, I want convert in a correct json. I have test with `json.encode()` but not work.

Thanks,

*String not json:*

```
{id: 2, status: 2, pseudo: giles, password: lmstvixKUKcmEKL, email: Barbara_VonRueden@yahoo.com, phone: 710-934-8381, birthday: 2022-03-26, resume: Velit unde maiores nostrum sit et voluptate perspiciatis repellat., avatar_path: avatar_8.png, active: 0, created_at: 2022-05-26 13:40:31, updated_at: 2022-05-28 13:04:44, age: 0, avatar: http://localhost/api_alligatorsdujeu/storage/app/gallery/avatars/avatar_8.png, family: {id: 8, name: TREMBLAY, newsletter: false, philibert: true, active: true, created_at: 2022-05-26 10:18:15.000, updated_at: 2022-05-26 10:18:15.000}}
```

*String json :*

```
{"id": 2, "status": 2, "pseudo": "giles", "password": "lmstvixKUKcmEKL", "email": "Barbara_VonRueden@yahoo.com", "phone": "710-934-8381", "birthday": "2022-03-26", "resume": "Velit unde maiores nostrum sit et voluptate perspiciatis repellat.", "avatar_path": "avatar_8.png", "active": 0, "created_at": "2022-05-26 13:40:31", "updated_at": "2022-05-28 13:04:44", "age": 0, "avatar": "http://localhost/api_alligatorsdujeu/storage/app/gallery/avatars/avatar_8.png", "family": {"id": 8, "name": "TREMBLAY", "newsletter": false, "philibert": true, "active": true, "created_at": "2022-05-26 10:18:15.000", "updated_at": "2022-05-26 10:18:15.000"}}
```

Comment: Could not grab where the problem is?

Comment: I have a String not Json and I want a String Json. because `json.decode(stringNotJson)` not work. I have a error _unexpected character (at character 3)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to convert a string to a json that doesn't match the json syntax, so any attempt in using the usual json methods will fail.

Your little trick is fine but I would suggest using a regular expression like so :

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
    String notJson = '{id: 2, status: 2, pseudo: giles, password: lmstvixKUKcmEKL, email: Barbara_VonRueden@yahoo.com, phone: 710-934-8381, birthday: 2022-03-26, resume: Velit unde maiores nostrum sit et voluptate perspiciatis repellat., avatar_path: avatar_8.png, active: 0, created_at: 2022-05-26 13:40:31, updated_at: 2022-05-28 13:04:44, age: 0, avatar: http://localhost/api_alligatorsdujeu/storage/app/gallery/avatars/avatar_8.png, family: {id: 8, name: TREMBLAY, newsletter: false, philibert: true, active: true, created_at: 2022-05-26 10:18:15.000, updated_at: 2022-05-26 10:18:15.000}}';
    String isJson = notJson.replaceAllMapped(RegExp(r'(?<=\{| )\w(.*?)(?=\: |, |})'), (match) {
      return '"${match.group(0)!}"';
    });
    print(isJson);
}
```

Might be subject to modifications if used on a more complex case to parse.

Comment: Thanks, the regex seems like a better solution !

Answer (score 1):

*Update :* I found a solution even if it is not optimized.

```
String convertToJson(String str) {
  str = str.toString().replaceAll('{', '{"');
  str = str.toString().replaceAll(': ', '": "');
  str = str.toString().replaceAll(', ', '", "');
  str = str.toString().replaceAll('}', '"}');
  return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `jsonEncode(jsonDecode(yourString));`
Use `jsonDecode(string)` this will return you a Flutter `Map` if the string is valid
After that,
use `jsonEncode(theResultMap)` to return it to string with double quotes

Comment: Thanks but jsonDecode(myString) throw error : `unexpected character (at character 3)` because my string don't have the double quotes.